# Find the analyticity of |z|

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I have been struggling finding the domain of analyticity in complex analysis, my teacher finds them with a drawing like the one I've attatched (in the pic they were asking for $\sqrt{z-1}=e^{1/2 \log(z-1)}$ if it helps):

[image: Photo of how my teacher solves it]

So I would appreciate if it was solved that way. I've tried to do it and got the image ($\{x+iy\in \mathbb{C}\ | \ x,y\geq 0\}$) but can't find the domain of $|z|$? Should I try to do it with the $$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ or some sort?

Comment: The values of $|z|$ are only reals.  So $|z|$ is analytic on no neighborhood in the complex plane.  The method of maps (as pictured) will only apply for functions analytic in some open set of the plane.

Comment: Here is a function not too different from yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2661434

Comment: @GEdgar wait what? Can you please expand a little bit on that? What do you mean "on no neighborhood in the complex plane"? And then how else am I supposed to find where the function is analytic without the drawings?

Comment: The diagram method works find on functions that are analytic.  But, since $|z|$ is nowhere analytic, these diagrams will not help.

Comment: @GEdgar how? I literally found the domain of analyticity of $\sqrt{z-1}$ with the drawing which isn't analytic?